# How to solve $u\frac{du}{dy} = yu$ where $u(x) = y'(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve:  $u\frac{du}{dy} = yu$ where $u(x) = y'(x) = \frac{dy(x)}{dx}$?

What I have done is (cancel u on both sides first):

$$du = ydy \longrightarrow u = c_1+\frac{y^2}{2}$$ so plug $u(x) = y'(x)$ in, we obtain

$$\frac{dy(x)}{dx} = c_1+\frac{y(x)^2}{2}$$

This ODE is not

1. linear
2. separable
3. exact (you can let $M(x,y) = 1$, and $N(x,y) = RHS$ and find that $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\neq \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$)

I am not sure how to go further and also can I cancel $u$ on both sides?

Comment: uit's separable .... juste integrate on dx and dy

Comment: @Isham There is a constant $c_1$. If there is no $c_1$, I am sure this is separable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's separable

$$\frac{dy(x)}{dx} =y'= c_1+\frac{y(x)^2}{2}$$

$$\int\frac{dy}{y^2 +2c_1} =\int\frac{dx}{2}=\frac x 2 +K$$

Substitute $y=u\sqrt{2c_1}$ for the integral...

$$\frac 1 {\sqrt{2c_1}}\int\frac{du}{u^2 +1} =\frac x 2 +K$$

$$\frac 1 {\sqrt{2c_1}}\arctan(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2c_1}}) =\frac x 2 +K$$

2) Starting from your first equation

$$u\frac{du}{dy} = yu$$
$$\frac{du}{dx} \frac{dx}{dy}= y$$
$$y''-yy'=y''-\frac 1 2 (y^2)'=0$$
$$y'-\frac 1 2 (y^2)=K$$
$$\int\frac {dy}{y^2+2K_1}=\frac x 2 + K_2$$